# Displaying an image in XSLT

Tags: xml, image, entity, xslt-1.0, embed

I want to embed an image in a certain table cell in **XSLT**, but cant seem to make it work.

I've tried several things that I found on in here, but none of them worked. I cant figure out how to select the image, embedded through entity in the DTD and display it in the browser through the XSLT.

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE games [
<!ELEMENT games (name, charcteristics)>
<!ELEMENT game (name, gameNumber)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT gameNumber EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT gameCover (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT characteristics (genre*,studio*,year*,review*)>
<!ELEMENT genre (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT studio (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT review (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST gameNumber gameID ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST genre gameNum1 IDREF #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST genre type (action|RPG|FPS|Puzzle) "action">
<!ATTLIST studio gameNum2 IDREF #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST studio studName (EA|Ubisoft|Gameloft|Bethesda) "EA">
<!ATTLIST gameCover picture ENTITY #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST gameCover format NOTATION (jpg|gif) #IMPLIED>
<!ENTITY FCp SYSTEM "upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/18/Far_Cry_Primal_cover_art.jpg" NDATA jpg>
<!NOTATION jpg PUBLIC "jpg viewer">
<!NOTATION gif PUBLIC "gif viewer"> ]>

<games>
    <game>
        <name>FarCry:Primal</name>
        <gameNumber gameID="qJCGc" />
        <gameCover picture="FCp" format="jpg"></gameCover>
        <year>2016</year>
        <review>lololo</review>
    </game>

    <characteristics>
        <genre gameNum1="qJCGc" type="FPS"></genre>
        <studio gameNum2="qJCGc" studName="Ubisoft"></studio>
    </characteristics>
</games>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <h1>
            <font face="" color="#EAC67A">XML Каталог за видеоигри</font>
        </h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!-- Image should be here -->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm new to XML and XSLT, please assist me.

Comment: What in the XML determines the name of the image? Is it the picture attribute of the `gameCover` element?

Answer (score 3):

It's not universally supported (worked for me in I.E., Chrome, and Safari, but not Firefox), but you can get the URI of the entity with `unparsed-entity-uri()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="//game">
        <h1>
            <font face="" color="#EAC67A">XML Каталог за видеоигри</font>
        </h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="{unparsed-entity-uri(gameCover/@picture)}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But... I note that there are a few problems in the source document. The URL isn't properly formed (no scheme), and the DTD has errors (the spelling of *characteristics* is inconsistent, the `game` element is incomplete, etc.).

This could cause you some problems.